# Combining very small p-values - Fisher's method gives 0

Tags: p-value, combining-p-values

I have 30 p-values all very small (varying between $10^{-140}$ and $10^{-110}$), and I want to combine them in some way to get a single statistic. I learned about Fisher's method, but if I apply it to those small p-values, what I get is 0, probably due to lost of precision. But I want to get a certain number, not 0, since my purpose is to do the same for multiple methods and compare the statistics for each of them (each of the methods give 30 p-values, again all very small). I get 0 for each of the the methods, although they are in fact different, and getting 0 for all of the methods makes it impossible to compare them. A way is to get the mean of the logarithms of the 30 p-values, but I am not sure how much it makes sense. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You get 0 for what exactly? - the test statistic or its p-value? Can you explain your calculation?

Comment: I get 0 for the p-value of the statistic. I am doing the calculation using `pchisq(-2*sum(log(pvals)), 2*length(pvals), lower.tail=FALSE)` in R. I think what I should do is to add `log.p=TRUE` to the parameters of `pchisq` function.

Comment: Edit the question to include that info. - it comes down to evaluating the cdf of the chi-squared distribution far out in the upper tail.

Comment: Just curiosity: did R really give you such small p-values?! Most commands only go to 2*10^-16 as far as I know

Comment: Yes, I used Wilcoxon test (`wilcox.test` in R) and it gave those p-values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If underflow is the issue, you could simply compare the sum of their logs (the mean of the logs is entirely equivalent)

   Note that Fishers method actually compares $-2\sum_{i=1}^k \log(p_i)$ to a $\chi^2_{2k}$ ... so Fisher would also be working on the log scale.
2. However, it's not clear to me that there's necessarily any particularly meaningful comparison between two sets of extremely small p-values. For starters, the values in the extreme tail will tend to be quite sensitive to even small deviations from assumptions.
3. Some people would argue that you shouldn't compare p-values at all.